# VBA function to get page's URL to extract gps coordinates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a little problem, thanks for whatever help you might bring :)

my **goal** : i want to create a vba function that receives an address and returns the gps coordinates related to this address. To do so, i want to open my address in Openstreetmap (or Google Maps) in order to extract the page's URL which has the gps coordinated within it.

**problem** : my function only works way, it open the address in the navigator but it won't return the URL...

my code :

```
Option Explicit
Function AdresseToCoordonnesGPS(URL As String)
    Dim navigateur As Object
    Set navigateur = CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute("microsoft-edge:" & URL) 
    navigateur.Visible = True
    Do While navigateur.busy And navigateur.ReadyState <> 4
       DoEvents
    Loop
    pause (3)
    
    Dim redirection As String 
    redirection = navigateur.locationUrl
    redirection = Right(redirection, Len(redirection) - InStr(redirection, "#"))   
    redirection = Right(redirection, Len(redirection) - InStr(redirection, "/"))
    AdresseToCoordonnesGPS = redirection
End Function
```

**result** : this function manages to open the link in the navigator (microsoft edge) it won't copy the page's URL, which i need in order to extract the GPS coordinates
here's what it return :

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you edit the first line of code? it says just `Func`

Comment: Note that if there is an error in your function you will very likeyly get a `#VALUE!` error in your cell. Write a procedure/sub to test your function and call it like `Debug.Print AdresseToCoordonnesGPS("YourTestURL")` This way your code will throw an exception and stop so you can debug it and see the actual error message.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to do what you're trying to do with Edge. It *would* be possible with Internet Explorer as you can read the URL of I.E. using the OLE automation - but Edge doesn't have that as an option. You might have luck using a 3rd party tool such as Selenium.

Comment: indeed you're right, i tried to use edge because IE is almost obsolete, but i'll change my code to use IE instead